# extern(al) problem

Tags: c++, extern

Why can't I compile this code?

```
   //main
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "X.h"
    #include "Y.h"
    //#include "def.h"

    extern X operator*(X, Y);//HERE ARE DECLARED EXTERNAL *(X,Y) AND f(X)
    extern int f(X);
    /*GLOBALS*/
    X x = 1;
    Y y = x;
    int i = 2;

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        i + 10; 
        y + 10;
        y + 10 * y;
        //x + (y + i);
        x * x + i;
        f(7);
        //f(y);
        //y + y;
        //106 + y;
        return 0;

    }

//X
struct X
{
    int i;
    X(int value):i(value)
    {
    }
    X operator+(int value)
    {
        return X(i + value);
    }
    operator int()
    {
        return i;
    }
};
//Y
struct Y
{
    int i;
    Y(X x):i(x.i)
    {   }
    Y operator+(X x)
    {
        return Y(i + x.i);
    }
};

//def.h
int f(X x);
X operator*(X x, Y y);
//def.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "def.h"
#include "X.h"
#include "Y.h"


int f(X x)
{
    return x;
}

X operator*(X x, Y y)
{
    return x * y;
}
```

I'm getting err msg:
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl f(struct X)"

Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct X __cdecl operator*(struct X,struct Y)"

Another interesting thing is that if I place the implementation in def.h file it does compiles without errs. But then what about def.cpp? Why I'm not getting err msg that function f(X) is already defined? Here shouldn't apply ODR rule. Second concern I'm having is that if in def.cpp I change the return type of f from int to double intelliSense underlines this as an error but program still compiles? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the word `extern`. It's the default anyway -- it doesn't mean anything for function declarations, and it should be avoided in any case in C++. if you're still having issues it's likely def.cpp is not being compiled into your program.

Comment: @Billy ONeal how is it possible that .cpp is not being compiled?

Comment: @Knowing: Could be set to Build: No in project properties, it could be not included as part of the project, it could have the exact same name as another .cpp file in the project which causes the compiled output to be overwritten, or Visual Studio could be getting confused and think the project output is up-to-date when it is not. There are probably some other things that could go wrong, but those are the ones I can think up right now. It's entirely possible that using `extern` has given the function C linkage, which would also cause the linker errors; hence my suggestion to remove it.

Comment: I think he means "not linked into", possibly by also not being compiled.

Comment: @Billy even though I've removed it I'm getting this same err. And what about the fact that I can have both definitions in two different files and I'm not getting err msg?

Comment: I restarted VS and the orig ver works. Unbeliveble. Didn't change nothing in proj. settings.

Comment: @Knowing me knowing you: Restarting VS probably triggered a rebuild-all which fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like def.cpp is not being used here.  As you point out, if def.cpp was being compiled, it includes def.h, and if the functions were defined in def.h, that would be a multiple function definition warning or error.

Check your project settings.